# SVG animate starts without being started

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg, svg-animate

I have an  inside a  that starts without the variables being started:

```
<rect height={5} width={5}>
    <animate 
        attributeName="height" 
        from={5} to={10} dur="2s" 
        begin={start ? "0s": "indefinite}/></rect>
```

The component is inside a SVG which rerenders to change the 'start' variable to start the animation. However, the animation starts immediately regardless of when I choose to rerender it. So if I press it as soon as I render the page it's on then it will work properly. However, if I rerender the component after 2 seconds, the animation will jump to the end value. If I start the animation 1 second after rendering the page the component is on then the animation will play from the middle. What is going on?!

Thanks

Comment: missing = sign? If not please provide a [mcve] i.e. something we can run ourselves.

Comment: Are there other animations on the page? If so the animation timeline may have run so if you say begin at 0s but the timeline is already at 2s then the animation will start 2s in.

Comment: For code formatting: copy and paste your formated code, without indentation of the first line. Then, press Strg+K.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick replies. @RobertLongson Yes there were other animations on the page but they all started with the same 'trigger'. Found the solution though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`begin` and `end` times, if used without a reference to some other clock, always reference the *beginning of the document*. So instead of setting the value to `0s`, you should use some other reference. Several possibilities come to mind:

1. Start on click or some other event. The `begin` value takes the form of `<id of event target element>.<event name>`:

   ```
    <rect id="grafic" height={5} width={5}>
      <animate id="animation" attributeName="height"
               from={5} to={10} dur="2s" begin="grafic.click"/>
    </rect>
   ```
2. Start from some other code. The `begin` value stays at `indefinite`:

   ```
    <rect id="grafic" height={5} width={5}>
      <animate id="animation" attributeName="height"
               from={5} to={10} dur="2s" begin="indefinite"/>
    </rect>
   ```

   but the animation is started by API call:

   ```
    document.getElementById('animation').beginElement();
   ```
3. For a more React-like feeling, define a wallckock value of "right now" at the time of setting the attribute:

   ```
    const rightnow = () => new Date().toLocaleTimeString()

    <rect id="grafic" height={5} width={5}>
      <animate id="animation" attributeName="height"
               from={5} to={10} dur="2s"
               begin={start ? `wallclock(${rightnow()})` : "indefinite"/>
    </rect>
   ```

Comment: Ah, that confirms my suspicion. I was trying to figure out how to solve it though. MDN doesn't give me a lot of documentation for these specifics as far as I can tell.

Comment: How would I trigger 'begin' upon a boolean being true without using event listeners and beginElement()?

Comment: Also, beginElement() will not work as the type of getElementById is an HTMLElement instead of SVGAnimateElement.

Comment: The complete spec and documentation of time formats is [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#TimingAttributes). As for the APIs, did you test that? The return value of `document.getElementById()` or `document.querySelector()` for an `<animate>` element should always be of class `SVGAnimateElement` and implement `SVGAnimationElement`. In the same vein, the `id.click` syntax should work for each referenced element, indiscriminate of whether it is from the HTML of SVG namespace.

Comment: All I know is that VSCode is giving me an error and not compiling with it, but I'll start a new query about it.